# Check if element contain something within

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p></p> // return true 

<p>something</p> //return false
```

I thought of using jquery's contains() but I think there's a better way of doing it in pure js?

Answer (score 1):

```
return element.innerHTML.trim().length == 0;
```

Comment: How about jquery version?

Comment: I don't know, but it's unnecessary, since this works in ordinary JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) or [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) in plain JS. Both return an array-like collection containing the children of an element. Both collections have a `length` property.

Note that both properties are live collections. You might want to shallow-copy them into an array. Here's an example of getting all children of body.

```
var hasContent = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.children).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the old innerHTML to avoid JQuery like you want:

```
function hasSomething(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element && (element.innerHTML || '').trim())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: `element.innerHTML` evaluates to true even if there are only spaces between the opening and closing tags. I would suggest using `element.innerHTML.trim()` or `element.innerHTML.length === 0` to perform the check.

Comment: If the element is empty, `element.innerHTML` already returns `''`, no need for `element.innerHTML || ''`. Also, IE<9 does not support `String.prototype.trim()` so, maybe using `element.innerHTML.length === 0` is a better option for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you've got a tag with id `mydiv`

```
<p id='mydiv'>Something</p>

if($('#mydiv').is(':empty'))
```

or

```
if($('#mydiv:empty').length)
```

can check whether it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

SOmething like:

```
var myTextField = document.getElementById('myText');
    if(myTextField.value != "")
        alert("nothing")
    else
        alert("Would you please enter some text?")      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check function in the code below will do the job, You just need to call it. I have attached code in both jquery and javscript.

HTML :

```
<p id="data">Some text</p>
```

Jquery :

```
<script>
function check()
{
    var len= $("#data").text().length;
    if(len==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.write(check()); // call check function
});
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function check() {
    var x = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
    if(x.length==0)
    return true;
else
     return false;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Tip: if you have an `if` to decide whether to return a `true` or a `false` you can just return the `if` condition itself (negate it, if you need the opposite), like `return len===0`

Comment: @Morre- you caught me on this one. Now I have edited it.